# Export/Import not working for a Enterprise Wiki Site

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I have a requirement of migrating a Enterprise wiki site from one environment to another. When I tried to import the files i could see the files getting imported, but at the end, an error occured and operation did not complete successfully. Both source site and destination site are sub sites.

I got the following error.

***[List] [Pages]   Error: A duplicate field name "f863c21f-5fdb-4a91-bb0c-5ae889190dd7" was found.
FatalError: A duplicate field name "f863c21f-5fdb-4a91-bb0c-5ae889190dd7" was found.***

It looks like the GUID id pointing to Wiki_x0020_Page_x0020_CategoriesTaxHTField0.

I tried both STSADM and PowerShell commands but same error I am getting. As per the MSDN documentation, EDIT: Both source site and destination site are sub sites. Another interesting thing is, if the source site doesn't exist then the command works fine. This is contradicting with the MSDN documentation. It says both source and destination sites need to be created with same site template..

When I tried with another fresh wiki site, it worked. I am sure the problem is with my customized wiki site but I am not able to find the cause.

I have posted same question in [MSDN Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/br/sharepoint2010setup/thread/29be1367-fdc2-49c2-bb7c-a88cb26c33d9)

Please help

Comment: SharePoint related questions would be very welcome on [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/) - you might want to consider posting it there, or better still asking for it to be migrated.

Comment: I posted it http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25506/export-import-not-working-for-a-enterprise-wiki-site

Answer (score 0):

had a similar problem, i found the field's name and got into it via browser

[rootSiteUrl]/_layouts/fldedit.aspx?field=[fieldName]

then i just deleted it.